# Is Kruskal-Wallis the right test?

Tags: anova, post-hoc, kruskal-wallis-test, two-way

I'm writing a research protocol and trying to work out the right test.

1. Is there a significant difference between the success rate (dependent variable, ratio data) for different repair materials (there will be approximately 5-8 materials; independent variable, nominal data) ?
2. Does repair timing (confounding variable, 3 options, nominal data) affect the success rate (dependent variable)?
3. Does perforation position (independent variable, 3 options, nominal data) affect the success rate (dependent variable)?
4. Effect of repair timing and perforation position on success rate?

I think it's the one-way ANOVA Kruskal-Wallis for questions 1-3, and a two-way ANOVA for question 4, but until today I had never heard of any of these! 
If the one-way ANOVA returns a significant result, should I then do an ad hoc test to identify which groups had a difference in means? If so, is there a specific one?
Do I have to specify a significance level for ANOVA?

My data will be extracted from several different articles and so there will be heterogeneity. Will that work with ANOVA?